# Разбитие строки и удаление части строки

Tags: java, android, регулярные-выражения, split

Есть строка

```
String s = "строка 1 | строка 2";
String[] sArr = s.split("|");
```

Вместо двух строк в `sArr` я получаю либо `sArr[0] = "строка 1 | строка 2"`, `sArr[1]` вообще пустая.Либо при этой же строке `s` в `sArr` попадает вся строка посимвольный.

В общем нужно регулярное выражение для разбития строки.И для удаления из строки ненужного например

```
строка (фыфы) = строка 
строка 232323 = строка
```

Answer (score 5):

Необходимо экранировать символ `|`, потому что он имеет специальное значение.

```
String[] sArr = s.split("\\|");
```

Для замены всех цифр можно использовать

```
"a12b54".replaceAll("\\d+", "x")
```

Comment: Так и делал только так "\|".Ваш вариант работает.С регуляркой по замене подстроки поможите или подскажите удобный онлайн тестер регулярок для java.

Comment: Нужно заменить скобки и что в них на пустоту,так же цифры.

Comment: Для цифр я написал, для скобок регексп `"\\(.*\\)"`. Попробуйте изучить сами, там не очень сложно.

Comment: Я примерно с ними знаком.Сейчас попробую.В replaceAll можно же совмещать выражения как в регулярке?Типа "\\d+ \\(.*\\)"

Comment: Можно, но не так. replaceAll находит и заменяет. Если сделать как у вас то он будет искать цифры а затем скобки. Нужно `"(\\d+|\\(.*\\))"`. Здесь `|` означает "или".

Comment: Ладно спасибо проверю позже

Comment: Поправка `"(\\d+|\\([^)]*\\))"`. Так будет работать даже если скобок больше одной пары.